# specifying paths for swagger-fox in a java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I recently was forced to upgrade the version for Springfox fox from 2.9.x to 2.10.0, after doing that the following code stopped working:

```java
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import java.util.Collections;

import static com.google.common.base.Predicates.or;
import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    private Predicate<String> paths() {
        return or(
                regex("/unit.*"),
                regex("/element.*"),
                regex("/resources.*"),
                regex("/calculation.*"),
                regex("/taxi.*")
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(paths())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(getApiInfo());
    }
```

After upgrading I noticed that the annotation @EnableSwagger2 changed to @EnableSwagger2WebMvc,
after making this change I also noticed that now they are using Java predicates instead of Google predicates.
This code does not compile anymore because of that or(...) method, anyone facing this issue, can someone share what is the new way of doing this in the newer version of swaggerfox.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the incompatibility of swagger and swagger-ui libraries.
Just update your swagger-ui dependency to 2.10.0 version.

Example, if you're using maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```